# How can I fix the "invalid character" error when creating a project in Azure Form Recognizer labeling tool

Tags: labeling, azure-form-recognizer

I'm trying to label data using the Azure Form Recognizer labeling tool.

1. create Azure account and Form Recognizer resource
2. download docker image
3. run local web site
4. create a project, fill in a project name using plain English string. 
   I get the “SAS token to blob storage” by opening the "Get Shared Access Signature" on my Azure Storage Account,  selecting all permissions,  and then paste that string into the "Azure blog storage / SAS URI*"  field in the tool.
5. provide my endpoint and key (endpoint url is copied from Azure Portal "quick start" page)
6. save.

result: 
cannot create a new project due to “invalid character”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"invalid character" can be caused by using the blob storage SAS token rather than the blob container SAS token. Try creating and using a SAS token to the blob **container** in the "Azure blob storage / SAS URI" field.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I should have picked the SAS token to the **blob container** instead of the blob storage.  These two terms are quite similar to each other,  and they are next to each other in the Azure Storage Explorer UI.  I re-created the project with the correct steps and it worked so far.

following are 2 screenshots from Azure Storage Explorer, hope this helps:

[image: pick the blob container] [image: set correct permissions, then create the SAS token]